# Create a list from two different list

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, drop-down-menu

I have two lists. One list of Person and one list of Organization.
I want to add these lists to each other and create a new list and then bind this list to a DropDownList.
It is noteworthy that I want to add another property to this list that when I want to select an item from DropDownList, it give me this item is Person or Organization.
How to I create this list?

Comment: Take a look at Linq's `Zip` function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx

Comment: Start with creating a class which both inherit from (f.e. `OrgUnit`) with a property `OrgType`. Then you can use a `List<OrgUnit>`  as DataSource.

Comment: Are your both list of same type?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Not sure if I agree with having both types inherit from a common class just for presentation purposes.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: It's probrably not the only place where he'll benefit from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rereading your question, perhaps you shouldn't use Zip (or perhaps there's a better way than what I'm about to post using it).

Create a separate class that can contain both, have it mark if it's a person or organization, then build a list of those:

```
public class PersonOrganizationEntry
{
    public Person Person { get; private set; }
    public Organization Organization { get; private set; }

    public PersonOrganizationType Type { get; private set; }

    public PersonOrganizationEntry(Person person)
    {
        this.Person = person;
        this.Type = PersonOrganizationType.Person;
    }

    public PersonOrganizationEntry(Organization organization)
    {
        this.Organization = organization;
        this.Type = PersonOrganizationType.Organization;
    }
}

public enum PersonOrganizationType
{
    Person,
    Organization
}
```

Then merge your lists together with this new type:

```
var persons = new List<Person>()
{
    new Person(),
    new Person(),
    new Person()
};

var organizations = new List<Organization>()
{
    new Organization(),
    new Organization()
};

var mergedEntries = 
        persons.Select(p => new PersonOrganizationEntry(p))
    .Concat(
        organizations.Select(o => new PersonOrganizationEntry(o))
    ).ToList();
```

Then you can bind your drop-down-list against this collection of `PersonOrganizationEntry`. Each "Person" entry will have an instance assigned to the entry's `Person` field and the `Type` will be `PersonOrganizationType.Person`. Vice-versa for organizations.